# Codeigniter MY_Model by Jamie

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is driving me nuts..

I have a fresh installation of CI 2.1.3.
Copied MY_Model from here: https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
to application/core.
Autoloaded **database** library in **autoload.php**
Configured the database.php inside config folder properly.

Extended the MY_Model class like below:

```
class User_m extends MY_Model{ 

    public $_table = 'user';
    public $primary_key = 'user_id';

}
```

And in the default controller:

```
$this->load->model('user_m', 'user');

$row = $this->user->get(1);
echo $row->email;
```

This is the simplest implementation to see how the CRUD lib works but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in MY_Model.php on line 135
```

Line 135 of MY_Model.php:

```
$row = $this->_database->where($this->primary_key, $primary_value)
                        ->get($this->_table)
                        ->{$this->_return_type()}();
```

Comment: Try it without renaming the model:  `$this->user_m->get(1);` - it might be that the extended model doesn't support the renaming.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the _set_database function of the class. I don t know why that function is there in the first place, since you can load the database from the CI config file.

Comment: what is on line 135? and should the `$this->load->model('user_m', 'user');` be `$this->load->model(array('user_m', 'user'));` enclosing the two models inside an array

Comment: Updated the question with line 135. As for the model loading. No

Comment: seems like no data base connection has been made can you check if a connection is successful? sorry for the loading i thought you were loading two models, if forgot the second param is renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$this->_db)
{
    $this->_database = $this->load->database();
}
```

No database object will be returned from $this->load->database();

From CI docs:

```
/**  
 * Database Loader  
 *  
 * @param    mixed   $params     Database configuration options  
 * @param    bool    $return     Whether to return the database object  
 * @param    bool    $query_builder  Whether to enable Query Builder  
 *                   (overrides the configuration setting)  
 *  
 * @return   void|object|bool    Database object if $return is set to TRUE,  
 *                   FALSE on failure, void in any other case  
 */  
 public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $query_builder = NULL)
```

Try:

```
if ( $this->db ) {
    $this->_database = $this->db;
} else {
    $this->_database = $this->load->database('default', true, true);
}
```

**Later edit:**
I found a fixed version of that model. Replace your core model with [this one](https://github.com/cryode/codeigniter-base-model/blob/603a7155b03c33353cbb7bd4a91828522722f023/core/MY_Model.php)

Comment: Just what I thought was the problem. Thank you